# X++ ttsbegin and ttsAbort

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a problem with X++.
Lets say I have a transaction that looks in pseudocode like this

```
Custtable custTable;
ARandomTable mytable;
;
ttsBegin;
   select forUpdate custTable where custTable.AccountNum == '4000';
   custTable.NameAlias = custTable.Name;
   custTable.update();
   ttsBegin;
      select forUpdate mytable where mytable.myField == 'abc';
      mytable.myField = 'xyz';
      mytable.update();
      //ups something wrong happened... please abort the last
   ttsAbort;
ttsCommit;
```

Why does the ttsAbort abort the whole transaction and not the one that was last begun ? Is there a way to avoid it ?

Comment: Some great answers below.  If possible the `//ups something wrong happened` should be converted to a `checkX` method that will be called before the first or even second `ttsBegin;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does the ttsAbort abort the whole transaction and not the one that
>   was last begun?

This behavior ensures the [transaction integrity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa622564.aspx) of the transaction that was started with the first `ttsBegin`. Basically this first `ttsBegin` is like saying: "Start a new transaction and with regards to the database consider everything in this transaction as a single (atomic) action. The transaction ends if you ecounter a `ttsCommit` (upon which the action will be executed against the database) or a `ttsAbort` (upon nothing will be done in the database)."

If after the first `ttsBegin` another `ttsBegin` is encountered, this is like saying: "For each `ttsBegin` you encounter after the first, ignore one `ttsCommit`."

Since a transaction is considered a single atomic action, you cannot just abort part of this action.

> Is there a way to avoid it?

In your case, no. However, there is a way to ensure that part of an transaction will be committed to the database, even if the complete transaction gets aborted. This is done using a separate `UserConnection` for the inner transaction. See [How to create a separate transaction using UserConnection to ensure your transaction is not rolled back at a higher level](http://www.alexondax.com/2013/10/how-to-create-separate-transaction.html) 
 for more information.

Comment: Answer looks good and the link you provided looks promissing. I will give it a try and let you know if it worked

Answer (score 4):

Just like SQL [`ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) `ttsAbort` rolls back all statements to the outermost transaction.

> Rolls back an explicit or implicit transaction to the beginning of the transaction

In the AX/x++ the same rule is for exceptions.

> ## Exceptions Inside Transactions
>
> If an exception is thrown inside a transaction, the transaction is automatically aborted (a ttsAbort operation occurs). This applies both for exceptions thrown manually and for exceptions thrown by the system.
>
> When an exception is thrown inside a ttsBegin - ttsCommit transaction block, no catch statement inside that transaction block can process the exception. Instead, the innermost catch statements that are outside the transaction block are the first catch statements to be tested.

And `ttsAbort` is [obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa609617.aspx). Use [`throw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa885149.aspx) instead.